Certain endpoints are not hit and return 404 error while app running on the server but works on localhost
My web app is developed in Angular and backend is developed in .Net Core.
After deploying it in docker on the server, I can visit most of the pages but certain endpoints return 404 not found error. These work fine on localhost.
Backend:
[Authorize(Policy = "IsDesigner")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DesignerController : ControllerBase
{
    ...

    [HttpGet("{project}/{loop}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetChecklistByLoopAsync(string project, int loop, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Frontend:
getTaskByProject(role:string,project:string):Observable<any> {
    const encodedProject = encodeURIComponent(project);
    let requiredurl: string; 
    requiredurl = `${this.apiUrl}/${role}/selection/${encodedProject}`;
    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json','Authorization':`Bearer ${this.getToken()}`}
    return this.http.get(requiredurl, {'headers':headers, observe:'response'});
  }

Error message:
polyfills.4cb30b968c6ea108.js:1 
 
 GET https://azeu1.pp.com:4200/api/Designer/selection/AA%20BB%20CC%2FDD%20EE 404 (Not Found)
main.11182255502544c4.js:1 
 ERROR 
wr {headers: lo, status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'https://azeu1.pp.com:4200/api/Designer/selection/AA%20BB%20CC%2FDD%20EE', ok: false, …}
error
: 
null
headers
: 
lo
lazyInit
: 
()=> {…}
lazyUpdate
: 
null
normalizedNames
: 
Map(0) {size: 0}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
message
: 
"Http failure response for https://azeu1.pp.com:4200/api/Designer/selection/AA%20BB%20CC%2FDD%20EE: 404 Not Found"
name
: 
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
: 
false
status
: 
404
statusText
: 
"Not Found"
url
: 
"https://azeu1.pp.com:4200/api/Designer/selection/AA%20BB%20CC%2FDD%20EE"
[[Prototype]]
: 
_S

The Nginx config is:
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name azeu1.pp.com;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass   http://pp_v3:5000/api/;
        }

        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name azeu1.pp.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}

But for the same endpoint running locally http://localhost:4200/api/Designer/selection/AA%20BB%20CC%2FDD%20EE, it works. And most of the features in the app work on the server, just this certain one does not.
Could someone tell me what is the potential cause?

you shouldn't be using a port in that URL.  Remove the ":4200" from your baseURL when in production.  (using an environments file?)

@browsermator I have to use the port since the Server holds lota of containers and the IT Team currently cannot provide me an unique IP for it. So I was told to use the Port for the time being.

ok, I think the endpoint is expecting 3 arguments there so it doesn't map.  You should probably also remove the content-type from header.  This is a GET so all parameters come from URL.  You are currently sending two, but not sure the routing is setup to map project/loop.  You should either send those as query params or setup the routing to infer to project/loop based on order.
